# How does a WCF stack with multiple custom channels work?

Tags: .net, wcf, frameworks, stack

I am creating a WCF stack consisting of 4 channels:

```
var binding = new CustomBinding(new List<BindingElement>()
{
  new CustomChannel_A_BindingElement(),
  new CustomChannel_B_BindingElement(),
  new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(),
  new TcpTransportBindingElement()
}
```

Both custom channels implement the `IDuplexSessionChannel` interface. However when a client sends a request towards this stack some unexpected things (at least to me) happen:

- The `Receive` method on the custom channels is never invoked. Instead only the `BeginTryReceive/EndTryReceive`method pair is
- It is the `BeginTryReceive/EndTryReceive`pair from custom channel A (top of the stack) which is invoked, not from custom channel B (bottom of the stack)

**My first question is:** Which circumstances control which of the `Receive` `BeginReceive/EndReceive`or `BeginTryReceive/EndTryReceive` is called?

**My second question is:** Why is it the method(s) on custom channel A (at the top of the stack) which is invoked and not custom channel B (at the bottom of the stack)?

I also want custom channel B to do multiple communication (handshakes) with the calling client before passing the final message to custom channel A.

**My third and final question is:** How can I achieve this? One of the challenges is to prevent channel(s) higher up the stack to be invoked i.e. somehow tell the WCF runtime that custom channel A should not be called.